# Javascript: I want to change the image in a div every time different text is rolled over

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies for the possibly vague question.

I am trying to make a list of bands which on rollover [of the band name] will change the image specific to that band. I was trying to do this as a switch statement but I can't get it working? I'm reasonably new to JavaScript so any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```js
function bandMouseOver(selection) {
  switch (selection) {
    case "1":
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test1.png'
      break;
    case "2":
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test2.png'
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test.png'
  }
}
```

```css
.bands {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.bands:hover {
  color: #E05A6D;
}
```

```html
<div id="headlines">
  <h2> Line Up</h2>
  <div id="imageHolder">
    <img id="bandImage" src="images/band_test.png">
    <p>BAND DESCRIPTION
      <p>
  </div>
  <div id="lineUpDay">
    <div id="days">
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver(1)">Bon Jovi</a>
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver(2)">Eminem</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quote in your mouse over to pass a string for the switch instead of the numbers 1 or 2 this will then switch correctly. I made the band names black so you can see it changing the image on hover.

```js
function bandMouseOver(selection) {
  switch (selection) {
    case "1":
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test1.png'
      break;
    case "2":
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test2.png'
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'images/band_test.png'
  }
}
```

```css
.bands {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.bands:hover {
  color: #E05A6D;
}
```

```html
<div id="headlines">
  <h2> Line Up</h2>
  <div id="imageHolder">
    <img id="bandImage" src="images/band_test.png">
    <p>BAND DESCRIPTION
      <p>
  </div>
  <div id="lineUpDay">
    <div id="days">
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver('1')">Bon Jovi</a>
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver('2')">Eminem</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you pass numbers into your function but switch against strings. Make them both numbers or strings and it will work (below I have swapped the switch for numbers)

```js
function bandMouseOver(selection) {
  switch (selection) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=1';
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=2';
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('bandImage').src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=3';
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.bands {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.bands:hover {
  color: #E05A6D;
}
```

```html
<div id="headlines">
  <h2> Line Up</h2>
  <div id="imageHolder">
    <img id="bandImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=0">
    <p>BAND DESCRIPTION
      <p>
  </div>
  <div id="lineUpDay">
    <div id="days">
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver(1)">Bon Jovi</a>
      <a href="#" class="bands" onmouseover="bandMouseOver(2)">Eminem</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is is better to switch on digits or is just passing a string ok as well?

Comment: Either, up to you really, I just like numbers as it will save on writing quotes everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer up an alternative solution that will be easier to manage, you can see the [completed code here](https://jsbin.com/zemuyupida/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

Instead of using a switch statement you can store the image on the actual `<a>` tag or in my example a `<li>` that wraps the `<a>`.  HTML elements have a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) that allows for you to store custom data attributes.  The use case for you would be to store the image as a custom data attr.

Next instead of adding the event handler directly on the element, you can just query the element from Javascript.  All of your elements have the "band" classname in common so we can use `document.getElementsByClassName('band')`.  Now [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns and [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).  You cannot directly iterate over an HTMLCollection with a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) statement since it isn't of type Array.  However, you can convert the collection to an Array using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

When you iterate over the elements you can then add the listers to it.  In mine I added your `mouseover` listener and set the background.  But I suspect that you will probably want to remove the image when the user `mousesout` so I added that as well.

Here is the directly relevant code to the above paragraph.  The rest is in the JSBin.

```
function initializeBandRollovers() {
  const bands = document.getElementsByClassName('band');
  Array.from(bands).forEach((b) => {
    b.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      b.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + b.dataset.img + ')';
    });
    b.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
      b.style.backgroundImage = null;
    });
  })
}
initializeBandRollovers();
```

- Select all of the bands `const bands = document.getElementsByClassName('band');`
- Convert the HTMLCollection to an Array `Array.from(bands)`
- Iterate over all of the bands `Array.from(bands).forEach`
- Add the `mouseover` and `mouseout` elements to each band item...

  b.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    b.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + b.dataset.img + ')';
  });
  b.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    b.style.backgroundImage = null;
  });